# How can I extract the estimated home value from a Zillow link?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want my code to be able to take the *Zestimate* value off [this page](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/5841-Round-Meadow-Rd-Hidden-Hills-CA-91302/19882656_zpid/) so I can work with it (in this case, `10,037,774`). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the website is returning incomplete data as it is recognizing the Python script. To handle that, you'll have to use a *fake* `User-Agent` to emulate a browser request.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/19882656_zpid/34.217551,-118.600674,34.122534,-118.723412_rect/12_zm/1_fr/', headers=headers)
```

This will give all the elements available in the page source. But now, many elements are dynamically generated with JavaScript. So, they are not available in the page source. The value you want is inside the `<span class id="yui_3_18_1_2_1523251661826_947">` which is seen in the developer tools upon inspecting the element.

But in the page source, this tag looks like

```
<span class=""> $10,037,734 <span class="value-suffix">   </span></span>
```

So, you can't use that `id` to get the value. You can get the `<span>` tag which contains the text *Zestimate* using `soup.find('span', {'data-target-id': 'zest-tip-hdp'})`. To get the next `<span>` tag, you can use [`find_next('span')`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next).

**Complete code**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/19882656_zpid/34.217551,-118.600674,34.122534,-118.723412_rect/12_zm/1_fr/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

zestimate = soup.find('span', {'data-target-id': 'zest-tip-hdp'}).find_next('span').text
print(zestimate)
#  $10,037,734
```

---

There's another way you can get this data. At the top of the page source, there's a tag that looks like

```
<meta property="zillow_fb:description" content="Zestimate&reg; Home Value: $10,037,734. "/>
```

You can find the tag using the `property` attribute and get the value of the `content` attribute using `['content']`. To get the price, do some simple string splitting.

```
meta = soup.find('meta', property='zillow_fb:description')['content']
print(meta.split(':')[1])
#  $10,037,734.
```

If you don't want the dot `.`, you can strip it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selenium` to better emulate a browser:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/5841-Round-Meadow-Rd-Hidden-Hills-CA-91302/19882656_zpid/')
result = re.findall('(?<=Home Value:\s)\$[\d,\s]+', d.page_source)[0]
```

Output:

```
u'$10,037,734'
```

Answer (score 0):

Zestimate is the second span in the div class="home-summary-row".

with beautiful soup use:

```
row  = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "home-summary-row"})
```

and then you should be able to select children of the div, or parse by lines.